# how to sort array object based on another object

Tags: javascript

it possible to sort and rearrange an array that looks like this:

```
items:[{
     id: '5',
     name: 'wa'
     },{
     id: '3',
     name: 'ads'
     },{
     id: '1',
     name: 'fdf'
     }]
```

to match the arrangement of this object:

```
 Item_sequence: {
        "5": {index: 1},
        "1": { index: 0 }
      }
```

Here is the output I’m looking for:

```
 items:[{
     id: '1',
     name: 'fdf'
     },{
     id: '5',
     name: 'wa'
     },{
     id: '3',
     name: 'ads'
     }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the index is supplied and if not take a lage value for sorting by delta of two items.

```js
var data = { items: [{ id: '5', name: 'wa' }, { id: '3', name: 'ads' }, { id: '1', name: 'fdf' }] },
    sequence = { 5: { index: 1 }, 1: { index: 0 } };      

data.items.sort(({ id: a }, { id: b }) => 
    (a in sequence ? sequence[a].index : Number.MAX_VALUE) -
    (b in sequence ? sequence[b].index : Number.MAX_VALUE)
);

console.log(data.items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript specifically, First you have to apply loop to your array "items":

```
`
 let newArr = [];
 items.map(obj=>{

//obj will be the element of items array, here it is an object.

 if(Item_sequence.obj[id] !== undefined) {
   /*this condition will be satisfied when id from items array will be present as a 
   key in Item_sequence array*/

   insertAt(newArr, Item_sequence.obj[id] , obj) 
  }
 else{
   newArr.push(obj);
 }
})
//After checking on whole array here you assign a newArr value to items array.
items=newArr;
```

Hope that it will help you.